# How can I use the session function to recall the current applicationid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

As example, I login in to the system ad...
But how can i use the session function to recall the current applicationid?
Which I need to store in form and to the other table of database..
Behind code.. vb not c# 
Thanks a lot.
Your guide is appreciate .

Example.. 
1. Login with the session fix (userid) in virtual studio.. 
2. I wanna recall it out (userid) .. How !! Problem 1
3. Fill the (userid) to other table in database. That Y !
4. Grid view data show with specific (userid) only.. in session !! Problem 2

Thank splattne !!

I think that show be replace the word (applicationid) to (userid) .. my mistaken... 
Cos after i recheck the table of aspnet_membership!!

Comment: Please try to explain it better...

Comment: I have some questions: what do you mean by "session fix (applicationid)? Is that something specific to your program/database? What do you mean "fill the ... to other table"? Insert that value in a table "SessionId, ApplicationId"?

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET Session isn't a function, but an object, more specifically a specialized Collection ([SessionStateItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateitemcollection.aspx)) kept in memory with a timeout specified. You can insert data (other objects) in that "container" using strings as keys like "UserName", for example:

```
Session("UserName") = "billg"
```

You can retrieve that value the same way:

```
Dim UserName as String = Session("UserName")
```

You can find an [Overview to Session State on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you are after but the SessionID will change event after the session starts until you actually store a value in Session. Better to come up with your own ID or SQL based identity and store that in Session.